# CommentForm design question about Django-comments package

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-comments

In Django's own comment framework, **[django-contrib-comments](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments)**, it has below `class` defined:

1. In `models.py`, `class Comment (CommentAbstractModel):` is defined.
2. In `forms.py`, `class CommentForm (CommentDetailsForm):` is defined.

**Q: since the comment framework is a comment-db-table driven package, why not we use `ModelForm` to create forms from models, instead of redundantly create another `CommentForm` class ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `CommentDetailsForm` inherits from `CommentSecurityForm`, which defines various util methods and performs custom validation. These forms also declare fields that are not contained in the `Comment` model. Yes, it was possible to use `ModelForm` instead of `Form`, but I think that this decision is not wrong because these forms need specific behaviors, `ModelForm` would have saved some lines of code (not many), but the actual implementation is more explicit. Using `ModelForm` with models is not a must.